# Problem in start up of MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am getting a message when I am trying to start up mysql server.

D:\Softwares\MySQL\MySQL\MySQL\bin>mysqld.exe
110825 16:20:41 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile 'D:\Softwares\MySQL\MySQL\MySQL\share\english\errmsg.sys
110825 16:20:41 [ERROR] Aborting

Please help me

Comment: Did you try re-installing mysql?

Comment: I got a copy of errmsg.sys from other system and pasted it in the correct place now mysql is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need an errmsg.sys for mysql to run correctly.